# Is is better to host two different websites on one tomcat instance?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Is is better to host two different websites on one tomcat instance?

OR

One tomcat instance for each website?

Answer (score 2):

same instant is fine.
it depends how loaded are the sites, and if the need special configuration and loaded modules, but it usually easier to maintain a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

Two tomcat instances would be a memory pig and no performance advantages.  Handle any unique vhosts, etc by the apache proxy to tomcat and serve the sites up via apache.